# How can I run php artisan and npm run electron at once?

Tags: laravel, electron

I tried to run `php artisan serve` and `electron .` by using npm but only the php artisan serve is activating. I can access the `127.0.0.1:8000` using the browser but the electron desktop app is not running.

```
"scripts": {
    "electron": "electron .",
    "start": "php artisan serve & npm run electron",
}
```

Comment: You need to put them in different processes. Since php artisan serve is ongoing it will block the electron script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the execution of the `php artisan serve` command does not end until you stop it, so the `npm run electron` command is never going to start.

Trying to run the serve command in background (like using `nohup`) will result in troubles when stoping the execution of the npm script: The artisan serve process won't stop, so rerunning `npm run start` will start a new serve process on the next available port: `8001`. You would need to find and kill each process manually.

The only option that comes into my mind is to set up an Apache/Nginx VirtualHost so you don't need to run the `php artisan serve` command.